# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-01-13 10:43:21.414  INFO 17304 --- [           main] c.s.c.gateway.CloudGatewayApplication    : Starting CloudGatewayApplication using Java 1.8.0_271 on Ajinas with PID 17304 (D:\microservice\cloud-gateway\target\classes started by user in D:\microservice\cloud-gateway)
2021-01-13 10:43:21.421  INFO 17304 --- [           main] c.s.c.gateway.CloudGatewayApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-13 10:43:22.659  WARN 17304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2021-01-13 10:43:23.161  WARN 17304 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.study.cloud.gateway.CloudGatewayApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2021-01-13 10:43:23.198  INFO 17304 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-13 10:43:23.261 ERROR 17304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.study.cloud.gateway.CloudGatewayApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:252) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:751) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:569) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at com.study.cloud.gateway.CloudGatewayApplication.main(CloudGatewayApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1090) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1071) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:522) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
... 20 common frames omitted`package com.study.cloud.gateway;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.EnableHystrix;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableHystrix
public class CloudGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: GATEWAY-SERVICE
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: order-service
        uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
        predicates:
        - Path=/order/**
        filters:
        - name: Circuit-Breaker
          args:
            name: order-service
            fallbackuri: forward:/orderFallBack 
      - id: payment-service
        uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
        predicates:
        - Path=/payment/**
        filters:
        - name: Circuit-Breaker
          args:
            name: payment-service
            fallbackuri: forward:/orderFallBack
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    
server:
  port: 8989
  
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream

hystrix:
  command: 
    fallbackcmd:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.1
 

com.study
cloud-gateway
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
cloud-gateway
Demo project for Spring Boot microservices

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the similar issue, mine was due to maven dependency import. Try starting the application by adding the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>        
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and also remove the existing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```